# CSS Selector not exists

Tags: css, wordpress

http://comtest.pointstarter.info/ is the site. In the top bar, The div named header-social is applying the css rule `#wrapper .header-social *` and shows that its coming from the site URL instead of any Css files attached. I want to remove the Important from this rule. Any one have idea?

Comment: Post the code here please.

Comment: Once css rules are tagged as "!important", you can't "unimportant" them anymore. At best you can write a more specific rule and hope that this more specific rule's "important" overrides to the original "important". You could try dynamically modifying the css ruleset: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/externalcss3.shtml

Comment: Thanks, Marc I want to know how it is being written (#wrapper .header-social *) while its neither in the default style.css nor in custom.css I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS rule comes from an  code block in the head section of the page. Starting from the end of the  block is the second  tag that you see.

Because it has an important word in the rule, yo change it you should use javascript to change the change the rule from javascript code.

If you can add JS, tell me and I will show you the piece of code.

[UPDATED]

Hey!

You have to add this piece of code to your CSS:

```
#myHeader .header-social {
  background-color: #FF0000 !important;
  height: 50px
}
```

and this piece of code to your JS file

```
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('header-v2');
        for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
            elements[i].id = 'myHeader';
        }
```

The trick is that we have added a more restrictive/specific rule than the other one, so although there is an "important" word, our rule wins. To create a more specific rule we have had to add a new #id via JS.

I have tested and it works. Hope it helps you!

Rafa

Comment: Thanks a lot Rafa... I can add JS code. Kindly paste it here.

Comment: I found the php statement in the header file which was responsible for this now it's all right. Bundle of thanks to Rafa Romero.